# PHP Pear Mail Can't Send Name With Unicode Characters

Tags: php, email, pear

On my server i'm using php pear package and when i send email, and i type in "name" field unicode characters, it doesn't send.. 
when i type latin characters, it works just fine.

so, guys, can you help me, to configure mail settings, that i could use in unicode (utf-8) characters too ?

code example:

`$headers = array("From" => "UNICODE NAME HERE <name@email.com>", "Subject" => "my subject");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type" => "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
    "From" => "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($unicode_name)."?=" . " <name@email.com>", 
    "Subject" => "my subject"
);
```

You should do the same with subject if you want to use UTF-8 characters there.