# Mail::factory Email Address Containing Latin Characters PHP

Tags: php, email, pear

All docs I have read only show the "From Name" containing latin chars but not how to encode the email correctly.  But all those examples don't show how to create a mailing form that will work when the user has a email address like "**Español@latin.com**".

Currently the below code will encode the name correctly.  But if the email address has a latin char in it.  It will not send.

```
$extraheaders['From'] =  $message->encodeHeader('From', "$name <$from>", "utf-8", "quoted-printable");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Pear Mail Can't Send Name With Unicode Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931519/php-pear-mail-cant-send-name-with-unicode-characters)

Comment: No it's not the same question.  My description explains that.  They are only talking about encoding the name, but the email address issue is not addressed.

Comment: have you tried encoding the email address in this way?

Comment: The email address is in the header version you see up there.  <$from>.  Your response made me try encoding the email separately but still nothing.  :/  Thanks for the suggestion.